# How to add "delete" function to the child button without affecting the fucntions of the parent?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a site where objects can be added to the list an then delete by the button.For now programm can add to the list and has some other functions,but I can't create a "delete" function to the buttons.I pretty much understand why:the function I created for the list(line-through and text color when clicked) is responding when I click on the appended button,because it thinks it belongs to the list.In particular,error is:

```
script.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at toggle (script.js:55)
    at HTMLUListElement.whenClicked (script.js:65)
```

But problem is,the only solution to the problem I can find is rewriting the whole program and also making it much more complex:I can create an array of the `li` objects that were written in HTML and then append them through while loop to the `ul` and in the same loop append the buttons,so they won't be one object.That's why I am asking you all for help.Can someone advise me how to fix situation withour making everything so complex in the end?Thanks in advance.

**CODE**

*Note:I created one duplicate of addButton function to see if I can just use buttons at the end of `ul`,but it's too much user unfriendly,that's why it is in the comments.Also there is small `deleteLi` function,that is suppoused to be acessed in the `addButton` function so that button can delete `li`.*

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var modify_list = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

var i = 0; //Stored value so we can acces to it later in the function
while (li.length > i) {
  li[i].classList.add(i);
  li[i].classList.add('done');
  li[i].classList.add('cursor');
  i++
}


var n = 0 
while (li.length > n){
 li[n].classList.toggle("done");
 n++
}


function inputLength(){
 return modify_list.value.length;
}

function addToTheList(){
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(modify_list.value));
 ul.appendChild(li);
 // createNewButton();
 modify_list.value = '';
}

function addAfterClick(){
 if (inputLength() === 0){
  alert("Please,don\'t enter the empty list");
 }else {
  addToTheList();
 }
}

function addAfterEnter(key){
 if (key.keyCode === 13 && inputLength() > 0){
  addToTheList();
 }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addAfterClick);

modify_list.addEventListener("keypress", addAfterEnter);


function toggle(number){
 li[number].classList.toggle("done");
}

ul.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);

function whenClicked(event){
 var li_number = event.target.className[0];
 //In JS it doesn't matter in some occasions if it's a string or number,I suppouse.
 // var li_number = Number(li_number_string);
 // console.log(li_number);
 toggle(li_number);
}



// Create buttons and their functions

function addButton(list_number) {
  var localButton = document.createElement("button");
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  localButton.innerText = "Delete";
  localButton.id = "myButton" + list_number;
  li[list_number].appendChild(br);
  li[list_number].appendChild(localButton);
  localButton.onclick = deleteLi(list_number);
}

// function addButton() {
//   var localButton = document.createElement("button");
//   localButton.innerText = "Delete";
//   localButton.id = "myButton" + list_number;
//   ul.appendChild(localButton);
//   // localButton.onclick = deleteLi(list_number);
// }

var list_number = 0 
// creates buttons for the li that were already created
while (li.length > list_number){
 addButton(list_number);
 list_number++;
}
// creates buttons for new li items.
function createNewButton(){
 var number = window['list_number'];
 addButton(number);
 window['list_number'] = number + 1;
}

function deleteLi(list_number){
 // var list_element = document.getElementById('myButton' + list_number)
 ul.removeChild(ul.childNodes[list_number])
}
```

```css
.done {
 color: red;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
.cursor{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>DOM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>What plans do I have till the end of the summer?</h1>
  <p>They are:</p>
  <input type="text" name="add activities" id ="userinput" placeholder="add activities">
  <button id="button">Send</button>
  <ul>
   <li>Learn German</li>
   <li>Learn Japanese</li>
   <li>Learn Java Script</li>
   <li>Physical activities</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addbutton function in the end  you should do : 
`localButton.onclick = () => deleteLi(list_number);`
So you have to pass a function to onclik instead of the result of deleteLi.

Comment: It's working!But I don't understand why it works.What makes difference?I dont' quite get the syntax.Also for some reason when I click for the first time it give an error and does nothing,but with the second click it works.

Comment: Didn't read you whole code to catch all bugs but the obvious one is that you are calling deleteLi at the time you are adding the button. So () => is function (){} so I am passing a function that will call deleteLi instead of calling it.

Comment: so,in other words,it means  = nofunction(){
deleteLi(list_number);
} ?Then I pretty much understand.